# How to access local variables of inner class

Tags: java, arrays, inner-classes

I have a class with a inner class of type array. I want to get access to the local variable in the inner class outside the outer class.

```
public class Fruits {

    public Citrus citrus[];
}
public class Citrus{

    public String lemon;
    public String orange;
}
```

Now I want to get the variable `lemon` from inner class outside of these classes.
I get the error class cannot be resolved to type

Comment: I guess, `lemon` and `orange` are instance variables of Citrus class, not local variables.

Comment: What is this all for? What are you trying to do? What is the purpose of using a nested class?

Comment: It looks like you should focus on simpler syntax before moving on to inner classes. The code that you have posted won't even compile due to syntactical errors.

Comment: I assume she's learning it. @anza could you post some workable code? I see A LOT of errors there. Please keep it simple, don't use one feature until you cannot build / test existing

Comment: You have some lines of code that don't resemble what you are talking about. Please provide a **true** [mcve]. Dont explain or talk about code - provide the **minimum** amount of code required to understand your problem please. And please understand: stackoverflow is not a dump for messy code. We are not going to walk you through the tons of errors in this code.

Comment: I have made changes to my code.

Comment: And what isnt working? If you have `Fruit somefruit = ...; ` then `somefruit.citrus[0].lemon` should work fine (assuming that you actually put some objects into citrus. Again: show as all the code, together with the compiler errors you got ...

Comment: I get this error Class<citrus> cannot be resolved to a type when I do somefruit.citrus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a way for u.
when u use array, u should use index for access each item of array.

```
public class Fruits {

    public Citrus citrus[];

    public void  test() {
        String temp=citrus[0].lemon;
    }

}
 class Citrus {
    public String lemon;
    public String orange;
}
```

now in u can get lemons and oranges from array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `public Fruits citrus[];` to `public Citrus citrus[];`

Answer (score 0):

I think all you want to is accessing the inner class from outside.
Below code snippet might be helpful if you just want to instantiate the inner class.

**Code is self explanatory just go through comment.**

```
public class Fruits {

    public Citrus[] Citrus;

    public class Citrus {

        public String lemon;
        public String orange;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("Citrus [lemon=");
            builder.append(lemon);
            builder.append(", orange=");
            builder.append(orange);
            builder.append("]");
            return builder.toString();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String...args)
    {

        //create the Fruits Object 
        Fruits f = new Fruits();
        //Array Declaration for inner class 
        Fruits.Citrus[] citrusArray = new Fruits.Citrus[1];
        //instanciate the inner class 
        Fruits.Citrus citrus = f.new Citrus();
        //assigning the value
        citrus.lemon = "Lemon";
        citrus.orange="Orance";

        //set instance of inner class into the array of inner class 
        citrusArray[0]=citrus;
        //setting array into the insatnce variable of Fruits class 
        f.Citrus = citrusArray;
        //printing the result
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f.Citrus));

    }
}
```